# Do I still need to create a .emacs file?

Tags: init-file, aquamacs

I have both aquamacs and emacs (installed from `brew`) on my macbookpro. I intend to learn to use aquamacs as my main editor/IDE.

When I use `C-h v user-init-file` in aquamacs, it reports the value as `~/.emacs`.

However when I do a `ls -a` I cannot find any  `~/.emacs` in `$HOME`. Instead I can see there is a `.emacs.d` directory.

I want to understand how does it work. Does emacs and/or aquamacs requires the presence of `~/.emacs` strictly? Can I just drop some `.el` files in ~/.emacs.d and expect emacs/aquamacs to pick them up automatically?

My goal is to enable projectile in aqauamcs. I have already downloaded it from MELPA via cask  in `.cask/24.4.1`, but I am at loss about how to enable projectile in aqacmacs.

Comment: Emacs can do everything that Aquamacs can do, except using the native OSX spell checker.  You will find more help with the regular version of Emacs as less people use Aquamacs.  Aquamacs checks for a `.emacs` on loading, but the developer of Aquamacs has a personal preference for a file called `Preferences.el`.

Comment: My question is very specific about the `.emacs` file. How will emacs deal with a missing .emacs? Will it just look into ~/.emacs.d ?

Comment: Emacs runs just fine without `.emacs` -- that file is were you store your personal user configurations.  People normally store their additional libraries inside a folder such as `~/.emacs.d/lisp`, and that additional directory would need to be added to the `load-path`.  You should look at the related threads regarding `.emacs` and `init.el` -- start with the official documentation:  https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Init-File.html

Comment: Thanks for a great pointer. Please make it an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: The night is young . . . :)  Other forum participants might mark this thread as being a duplicate of other related threads dealing with this issue, in which case the thread will be closed.  I'm not sure this particular thread is sufficiently different myself, so I'll leave it as is for now.

Comment: That's a problem. I have searched for `.emacs` in the site and in the first 3 to 4 pages of results I don't see a similar questions...

Comment: An example Google search:  `.emacs .emacs.d` or specific to your operating system  `.emacs .emacs.d osx`

Comment: @lawlist i don't think this is a duplicate. Even if it is, you still shouldn't put answers in the comments.

Comment: @erikstokes -- if you or another forum participant would like to post an answer, please be my guest.  The question deals with a *compare and contrast* between Emacs and Aquamacs as to `.emacs` and `.emacs.d`, yet also deals with the fundamental usage of a `.emacs` file.  Aquamacs also uses `Preferences.el` and other customizations.  The original poster is most interested in how to get Projectile up and running using Cask, and I know nothing about those. In a nutshell, there are several issues and the answers could conceivably become a treatise.